# Collection method values not resetting array keys after using forget

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a nested array of objects inside an array of objects.

`Pages` hasMany `sections`

I am trying to unset the nested sections and reset their array keys but to no avail.

```php
foreach ($pages as $pageKey => &$page) {
    foreach ($page->sections as $sectionKey => $section) {

        // Remove sections with no questions 
        if ($section->questions->count() < 1) {
            $page->sections->forget($sectionKey);
        }
    }

    $page->sections = $page->sections->values()->all();
}
```

However, the section keys are not being reset.

[image]

Comment: Are you getting this `$pages` collection from the database?

Comment: @HCK yes I am. I thought values would reset the keys

Comment: Why don't you use except on laravel collection

Comment: @RutvijKothari you mean like so `$page->sections = $page->sections->except([$sectionKey]);`

Comment: @AngadDubey Yeah like that. If you can paste your object it'll be easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

What (I assume) you are trying to do is get all the `Page`s with `Section`s that has at least `Comment`s. In order to accomplish this you could do this in one query:

```
$pages = Pages::with(['sections' => function ($query) {
                    $query->has('comments');
                }])
               ->get();
```

With this, you are eager loading the `Section`s related the every `Page` but just the ones that has at least one Comment linked to them.

---

You can check the documentation related to this topics:

- [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)
- [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)